# Rectangle clockwise movement

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to make a Windows Forms Application where rectangle moves clockwise. Here's the image.
[image]

And here is my code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int x;
    int y;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Crimson, x, y, 20, 20);
    }

    private void movingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (x < 750)
            {
                x += 5;
            }
            else if (x == 750 && y < 340)
            {
                y += 5;
            }
            break;
        }

        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

I understand why I can't go further. If I make new if statement with **x -= 5** it will be activated simultaneously with the while loop. 
What I can't understand is how to separate the new commands (***x -= 5*** and ***y -= 5***) so it would be activated only after my first while loop is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured it out. I did it like this.

```
while (true)
        {
            if (x < 750 && y == 0)
            {
                x += 5;
            }
            else if (x == 750 && y < 340)
            {
                y += 5;
            }
            else if (x > 0 && y >= 340)
            {
                x -= 5;
            }
            else if (x == 0 && y > 0)
            {
                y -= 5;
            }
            break;
        }
```

But I have a feeling that there is a more simple and elegant way to do this. Can anyone suggest something better?

Comment: meh same idea, but you typed faster ;-)

Comment: a more elegant way might be to remember the direction you are going to, then in each iteration check, if you hit an obstacle (in this case the end of the canvas) and then change the direction based on that...

Comment: and btw why do you make this in a while(true) loop if you break that loop unconditionally in the end?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yeah I know, I was just trying various things w/ IFs and WHILEs and forgot to delete it )

Comment: @Rooxie i'd recommend to create your own Rectangle class that has methods like `Move(Direction d, int speed)` and this direction is enum with four options : left top right bottom...

Comment: @Fabjan I don't fully understand how to do that. Probably because of my poor knowledge of syntax. I mean, I know how to create an enum with directions and how to make rectangle move when certain keys are pressed. But I don't know how to do that in a separate class and how to address to it in timer.

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not know where you want to go from there, I will provide you with the most staight forward solution:

```
if (y <= 0 && x < 750)
{
    x += 5;
}
else if (x == 750 && y < 340)
{
    y += 5;
}
else if (y >= 340 && x > 0)
{
    x-=5;
}
else if (y > 0 && x <= 0)
{
    y-=5;
}
break;
```

You may have to tweak the values a bit, but I guess you can figure it out from here.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need a while loop since you are using a timer, also do not check constant values in your if statements as these values will not work if you change the form size.

Use the following code:

```
private void movingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (y <= 0 && x < this.ClientSize.Width-20)
    {
        x += 5;
        y = 0;
    }
    if (x >= this.ClientSize.Width - 20 && y< this.ClientSize.Height-20)
    {
        x = this.ClientSize.Width - 20;
        y += 5;
    }
    if(y>= this.ClientSize.Height -20)
    {
        x -= 5;
        y = this.ClientSize.Height - 20;
    }
    if (x <=0 && y >0)
    {
        x = 0;
        y -= 5;
    }

    Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: I've started learning how to code just to weeks so I didn't know about this "this.ClientSize.Height/Width". I don't even know what is it called. Method, right? Thank you for the enlightenment.